Access AWS resource in another region
My project is one way s3 bucket replication. The destination bucket and KMS key are in us-east-2. In my Terraform module for the source bucket and replication I'm unable to access the KMS key ARN or S3 bucket as data sources. I get the error below from AWS which is correct, the key is in Ohio, However when I add provider = aws.dest to the data source, a new error comes up also below. Thank you if you can spare a moment on this problem.
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region[1]
  alias  = "dest"
}

data "aws_kms_key" "dest_kmskey" {
  key_id = "3b88109a-a89a-4726-a0cd-206ffd129a65"
}

 Error: reading KMS Key (3b88109a-a89a-4726-a0cd-206ffd129a65): NotFoundException: Key 'arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:339712700897:key/3b88109a-a89a-4726-a0cd-206ffd129a65' does not exist
│
│   with module.s3.data.aws_kms_key.dest_kmskey,
│   on s3/data.tf line 7, in data "aws_kms_key" "dest_kmskey":
│    7: data "aws_kms_key" "dest_kmskey" {

data "aws_kms_key" "dest_kmskey" {
  provider = aws.dest
  key_id = "3b88109a-a89a-4726-a0cd-206ffd129a65"
}

Error: Provider configuration not present
│
│ To work with module.s3.data.aws_kms_key.dest_kmskey its original provider configuration at module.s3.provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"].dest is required, but it has been removed. This occurs
│ when a provider configuration is removed while objects created by that provider still exist in the state. Re-add the provider configuration to destroy module.s3.data.aws_kms_key.dest_kmskey, after which
│ you can remove the provider configuration again.

